# I cannot POST using express while following MVC

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build a simple to-do list. I keep getting a cannot POST error trying to add a to-do using a form to submit. I'm not sure if I'm linking my files correctly or not while trying to follow MVC. Am I missing a module?

app.js (trimmed down because SO says I have mostly code)

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

// config.env is where all the global variables are stored.
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

// This call connects to mongodb.
connectDB();

// Initialize app
const app = express();

// Body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// Handlebars
app.engine(".hbs", exphbs({ extname: ".hbs" }));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

// Sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI }),
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
// app.use("/todo", require("./routes/todo"));

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on PORT ${PORT}`)
);
```

todo.js in Route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const todosController = require("../controllers/todos");
// const { ensureAuth, EnsureGuest } = require("../middleware/auth");

router.get("/", todosController.getTodos);

router.post("/addTodo", todosController.addTodo);
```

todo.js in Controller

```
const Todo = require("../models/todos");

module.exports = {   
  addTodo: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Todo.create({
        todo: req.body.todoItem,
        done: false,
        googleId: req.user.googleId,
      });
      console.log("To do has been added!");
      res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },
};
```

handlebars form

```
  <form class="center" action="/addTodo" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To Do" name="todo" />
    <button type="submit" class="submitButton">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
  </form>
```

and lastly my folder structure

[image]

Comment: `app.use("/todo", require("./routes/todo"));` commented. Isn't it the issue?

Comment: I uncommented it and unfortunately, it still gives me `cannot POST`

Comment: Shouldn't `action="/addTodo"` be `action="/todo/addTodo"` ?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes! Can you explain why? Is it from `app.use("/todo", require("./routes/todo"));`? The first `"/todo"`?

Comment: Exactly. By this line you say that all routes in `require("./routes/todo")` should be under `/todo`